# JPA: Equivalent for Oracle's REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: java, regex, oracle, jpa, named-query

I have following Oracle SQL query:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col, 0, INSTR(col, REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '\.\d+$')) -1) AS col_new, col as col_orig AS col_orig FROM tab;
```

I have data in table like:

```
col
ABC.A.01
ABC.A.02
```

Above query returns results like:

```
col_new  col_orig
ABC.A    ABC.A.01
ABC.A    ABC.A.02
```

I am trying to migrate it to JPA named query. Till now I could make query only like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(f.col, 0, LENGTH(f.col) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(f.col))), f.col FROM tab f;
```

I did this as I was not able to find equivalent in JPA for Oracle's REGEXP_SUBSTR. My JPA named query fails in data examples like ABC.A.P01.

Can you please let me know how can I migrate my SQL query to JPA named query using equivalent for REGEXP_SUBSTR.

Comment: It's probably easier to do this in Java (using `replaceAll()`) after you have received the data from the JPA call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there is no equivalent for REGEXP_SUBSTR in JPA. So I decided to stick to native query execution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipselink, use SQL to integrate SQL within a JPQL statement. This provides an alternative to using native SQL queries simply because the query may require a function not supported in JPQL.

The SQL function includes both the SQL string (to inline into the JPQL statement) and the arguments to translate into the SQL string. Use a question mark character ( ? ) to define parameters within the SQL that are translated from the SQL function arguments.

You can use SQL to call database functions with non standard syntax, embed SQL literals, and perform any other SQL operations within JPQL. With SQL, you can still use JPQL for the query.

Example

```
select o from Entity o order by SQL('REGEXP_SUBSTR(?, ''[0-9]+'', 1, 1)', o.code)
```